# What are the best practices for troubleshooting and improving the efficiency of file transfers between computers on a local network?"

Tags: networking, lan, tftp

What are the best practices for troubleshooting and improving the efficiency of file transfers between computers on a local network?"

Comment: Improving *efficiency* (throughput per resource use) or rather *performance* (throughput per time period)? Since you've tagged TFTP, is that on purpose or just as an example?

Comment: Your question is too broad currently. You should ask specific questions, see [ask]. Also, protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off topic here, we can only help you with the network itself. Additionally, please provide a good description of your network (perhaps a diagram) and the problems you face.

Answer (score 2):

When troubleshooting slow file transfer speeds between two computers on the same LAN, you can follow these troubleshooting steps and potential solutions:

1. Check network connectivity: Ensure that both computers are properly connected to the network and can communicate with each other. Verify that the network cables are securely plugged in, and if using Wi-Fi, check for a strong and stable connection.
2. Test network speed: Use network diagnostic tools or speed testing websites to measure the actual network speed between the two computers. This will help determine if the issue is related to the network or specific to file transfers.
3. Check hardware and drivers: Ensure that the network interface cards (NICs) on both computers are functioning correctly and have up-to-date drivers installed. Faulty hardware or outdated drivers can impact network performance.
4. Scan for malware or viruses: Run a malware or antivirus scan on both computers to check for any malicious software that might be consuming network resources and slowing down file transfers.
5. Check network congestion: Determine if there are other devices or applications on the network consuming excessive bandwidth. Close any unnecessary programs or limit their bandwidth usage to free up network resources for file transfers.
6. Optimize network settings: Adjust network settings such as the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) size, TCP window size, or Quality of Service (QoS) settings to optimize network performance for file transfers. Consult the documentation or seek guidance on the recommended settings for your specific network environment.
7. Consider network equipment: Evaluate the performance of network switches, routers, or access points in your network infrastructure. Outdated or inadequate networking equipment might limit data transfer speeds. Upgrading or reconfiguring the network equipment can help improve file transfer performance.
8. Enable jumbo frames: If supported by your network devices and operating systems, enabling jumbo frames can increase the efficiency of file transfers by allowing larger packets to be transmitted.
9. Use wired connections: If possible, connect both computers directly using Ethernet cables instead of relying on wireless connections. Wired connections generally offer more stability and higher speeds compared to wireless connections.
10. Check disk performance: Examine the disk drives on both computers to ensure they are not causing a bottleneck. If a hard drive is slow or fragmented, it can affect file transfer speeds. Consider optimizing or upgrading the storage devices if necessary.

Comment: *adjust [...} TCP window size* - the TCP window size is a dynamic parameter adjusted by (mostly) the data receiver, highly influenced by local processing capabilities, bandwidth and congestion detection. If you mean the *TCP window scale option*, that is generally recommended and required for high-bandwidth or high-latency links.

Comment: (Touching the limit of what's on topic for this board, because it's about end systems/servers):  Where I work, the cloud/S3 team is tracking the **rate of TCP SACK occurrences** in the IP stack of their storage nodes (CEPH clusters). Usually, their cluster nodes have a pretty well balanced traffic pattern of in/out traffic (well above 15 Gbps of sustained traffic across our spines). To them, a raising rate of TCP SACKs is an early warning sign that packets are lost somewhere, and that the data flows between their cluster nodes are not happening quite as good as they could. –

Answer (score 0):

- Use Spanning Tree protocol, and configure it with a good understanding of it.
- Don't enable PortFast (to avoid unintentional broadcast storms)
- Monitor and graph each switchport at least every minute for CRC errors, collisions, duplex/speed mismatches, dropped packets. Understand what is normal, and what is abnormal, for all of these criteria, and make sure to take action when an abnormality is encountered.
- You should be able to achieve all of this using SNMP.